# Escurecer o segundo plano ao abrir janela/div modal

Tags: html, css

Tentei criar algo do tipo `modal`, assim:

```
.try-modal{ 
    position: absolute;
    top:35%;
    left:25%;
    right: 25%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Chamo a `<div class="try-modal">` com `Jquery`, até ai tudo bem. Mas agora eu queria que a parte de trás, depois de aparecer este "modal", o que estivesse em 2º plano ficasse meio escuro como se fosse o modal do `bootstrap`. Há algum código ou *tricks* para fazer isso?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considerando que toda a funcionalidade está ok (como você afirmou na questão), basta fazer com que ele adicione um 2º elemento, feito isso, controle a exibição com o `z-index`.

Exemplo:

```
.try-modal-overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    background: rgba(#000, .4);
    z-index: 2;
}
.try-modal{
    position: absolute;
    top:35%;
    left:25%;
    right: 25%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 3; 
}
```

Assim o elemento `try-modal-overlay` ficará atrás do seu modal e com fundo preto transparente.

---

Uma alternativa seria usar o elemento `:before` em seu `css`, eliminando a necessidade de adicionar outro elemento com `jQuery`.

```
.try-modal:before {
    content: '';
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    background: rgba(#000, .4);
    z-index: 2;
}
.try-modal {
    ...[demais estilos]...
    z-index: 3; //Não esqueça de alterar esse index também
}
```

Eu, particularmente, prefiro a primeira opção pois fica mais segmentado, mas fica a seu critério.

Comment: Então basicamente é só criar uma outra camada

Comment: @programmer2016 isso. Você pode usar outra técnica de CSS, utilizando o before, vou atualizar a resposta.

Comment: Obrigado @CelsomTrindade